# WCF user identity issue when try to impersonate

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, silverlight, impersonation

I have WCF 3.5 service written by other company but I have source code. I have two clients, first is Silverlight (written by the same company) and second ASP page created by me.

I have following error on WCF site:

```
using(((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate())
{
    SomeClass.SomeMethod();
}
```

The Identity is almost the same.

Identity for silverlight call:

```
Name=Contoso\Administrator
Authenticated=True
Type=Negotiate
ImpersonationLevel=**Impersonation**
IsAnonymous=False
IsGuest=False
IsSystem=False
```

Identity for ASP Web call:

```
Name=Contoso\Administrator
Authenticated=True
Type=Negotiate
ImpersonationLevel=**Identification**
IsAnonymous=False
IsGuest=False
IsSystem=False
```

So the difference is in ImpresonationLevel value. Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

Exception:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)
File name: 'System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070542): Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnAbort()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.System.IDisposable.Dispose()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Client.WsTransfer.WsTransferClient.Put(Message request) 
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Client.WsTransfer.WsTransferClient.Put(PutRequest request) 
   at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Client.DefaultClient.Put(RmResourceChanges transaction) 
   at SomeClass.SomeMethod(some_parames)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem.

To switch ImpersonationLevel from Identification to Impersonation you must update the client wcf behavior configuration. It should looks like this (the most important is the **allowedImpersonationLevel** attribute):

```
<system.serviceModel>   
    <client>
      <endpoint ... 
                behaviorConfiguration="ImpersonationBehavior" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="ImpersonationBehavior">
             <clientCredentials>
                  <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" />
             </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

By default WCF use **Identification** if nothing is specified.